# How did a calendar icon make it to my Lock Screen?

Tags: ios, iphone

The other day I looked at my Lock Screen and to my surprise there was a calendar looking icon on the bottom left.  I thought it was kind of odd since I've never seen anything in the bottom left.  So I tapped it and sure enough my calendar came up.

This was kind of handy, so I locked the phone again, but the icon was gone.  I researched it and the closest I came up with is [location based app recommendations](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/06/03/ios-8-apps-quick-access/).

The odd thing is that I had nothing on my calendar on that day or in the vicinity of where I was at.

So how exactly did the calendar icon make it onto my Lock Screen and how to get it back?

Answer (score 3):

This is iOS 8 new feature called **Handoff** more info [here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6337).

> Continuity lets you seamlessly move between your iPhone, iPad, and Mac, or use them together.
>   (…)
>   Use Handoff with Apple apps such as Mail, Safari, Maps, Messages, Reminders, Calendar, Contacts, Pages, Numbers, and Keynote. Start a document, email, or message on one device and pick up where you left off on another device. You can also use Handoff with some third-party apps.

[image]

Comment: That's all good, but I don't have a Mac :)  Afaik, Handoff requires Yosemite.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You do NOT need Yosemite to run handoff or continuity. In fact it's purpose is for all devices that use your iCloud account, so if you have an iPad and an iPod and an iPhone the handoff icons will show up. They are independent of a Mac, to turn it on in your phone go to Settings > General > Handoff & Suggested Apps.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek it wasn't directed towards you, it was directed towards AngryHackers comment. Thats why I stated yours should be the accepted answer and elaborated on how it works with all devices independently

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek my mistake for not tagging him

Comment: @soulshined I see...  Tangent question... is there a way to interact with Handoff from windows?

Comment: @AngryHacker You should post that as a separate question so future question-seekers can have a direct path of resource to find a related answer. They more than likely won't read these comments to find out.